# Blackberry persistent object giving issues

Tags: java, blackberry

I am working with persistent store  and persistent object.I am being able to save values.I am storing each primitive into a vector and then saving the vector.So what happens now,when i start the app and say save three values.Those values are stored in the vector.Than if i start the app,n check for those values,its displaying the saved values properly.Now if i say again save two more values,than total saved value in the vector should be 5.But when i close the app and restart it.It shows only the last two values which i saved,the earlier three saved value is not displaying.Please help me

```
package com.kcrw.ui;
import java.util.Random;

import net.rim.device.api.system.PersistentObject;
import net.rim.device.api.system.PersistentStore;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.kcrw.model.Song;

import net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays;
import net.rim.device.api.util.Persistable;

public class Persist implements Persistable{

    public static PersistentObject abc;
    public static PersistentObject abc1;
    public static PersistentObject abc2;
    public static PersistentObject abc3;
    public static String b;
    public static String c;
    public static String d;
    public static String e;
    public static Vector vect;
    public static Vector xyz=new Vector();
    static {
          abc   = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0xb92c8fe20b256b82L);
          abc1   = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0xa94f6433aaf45909L);
          abc2   = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0xfbe29f690c998fb1L);
          abc3   = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0x67a6bd7c03940754L);
    }

    public static void data(){
    synchronized (abc) {

        abc.setContents(((Song) MoreInfoSongDetails.shows.elementAt(MoreInfo.listFieldIndex))
                .getTitle());
        abc.commit();
         }


synchronized (abc1) {

        abc1.setContents(((Song) MoreInfoSongDetails.shows.elementAt(MoreInfo.listFieldIndex))
                .getAirtime());
        abc1.commit();
         }


synchronized (abc2) {

    abc2.setContents(((Song) MoreInfoSongDetails.shows.elementAt(MoreInfo.listFieldIndex))
            .getAlbumImage());
    abc2.commit();
     }
synchronized (abc3) {
      System.out.println("vector size is"+xyz);



    abc3.setContents(xyz);

    abc3.commit();
     }  

}

    public static String getTitle() {
        synchronized (abc) {

            b= (String)abc.getContents();
            //xyz.addElement(b);
            return b;
        }
    }
    public static String getTime() {
        synchronized (abc1) {

            c= (String)abc1.getContents();
            //xyz.addElement(c);
            return c;
        }
    }

    public static String getImage() {
        synchronized (abc2) {

            d= (String)abc2.getContents();
            //xyz.addElement(d);

            return d;
        }

    }
    public static Vector save() {
        synchronized (abc3) {

            vect= (Vector)abc3.getContents();
        int i=vect.size();
        for(int b=0;b<i;b++){
            System.out.println("element at"+b+"is"+vect.elementAt(b));
        }
            return vect;
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that assigns anything to the vector. Am also confused that your "save" function reads the vector from the persistent store and your "data" method stores the vector.

Comment: Actually i am really sorry,the methods where i commented out xyz.addElement() in getTitle(0,getImage(),getTime(0 are the places where i am adding elements to the vector xyz.It shouldn't be commented.But the prob still remains what i described above

Comment: i think each time i call this class vector xyz is recreated as we are using new vector(),bt if i dont use new vector,i get null pointer exception

Answer (score 1):

Your code example isn't great, but saving and restoring a vector is quite trivial, as shown here:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html

I incorporated this into a little [tutorial](http://www.blackberryprogramming.com/tutorials/object-persistence/) on object persistence. There's also a PowerPoint deck [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CFgQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcmer.cis.uoguelph.ca%2Fcmer-ak%2FAcademicKit-V1.0%2FTeaching-Modules%2FDatabaseSystems%2FDB_slides_2.ppt&ei=VIJJTfrLC5PQsAP3xbCXCg&usg=AFQjCNEBSP_Z01CG8nx0xCuf3phf5waMlQ) that gives even more details.

Look through those pages and you should be able to find your problem.\

Comment: Thnx for your help.The thing is that i can save and retrive for a single go.But when i close the app and start again,and save new values,then the old saved values goes off,and only the newly saved valued is displayed

Comment: You must read the old vector in whenever your app starts. Otherwise you just end up writing over it.

Comment: Here is a SOF example I posted a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805182/how-do-i-use-the-persistent-object-store-in-blackberry/3808672#3808672