# Blackberry: how to make a data structure (for example Hashtable) persistable?

Tags: blackberry, persistence, hashtable, persistent-storage

I have this code which works well:

```
static {
    myStore = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(MY_LONG_KEY);
    myList = (Vector) myStore.getContents();
    if (_storedStations == null) {
            myList = new Vector(4);
            // prepopulate with fake data
            myList.addElement(new MyItem("Eins"));
            myList.addElement(new MyItem("Zwei"));
            myList.addElement(new MyItem("Drei"));
            myList.addElement(new MyItem("Vier"));
            myStore.setContents(myList);
    }
}

class MyItem implements Persistable {
    .....
}
```

probably because [the PersistentObject doc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentObject.html) says:

**Implicit persistance**

*Notice that some classes are implicitly persistable: Boolean, Byte, Character, Integer, Long, Object, Short, String, Vector, Hashtable.*

*Also note that, when you persist an object, any persistable object it refers to will also get persisted.*

But what about other data structures? For example - instead of the Vector used above - I'd like to have a [Hashtable](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Hashtable.html) with keys: Strings and values: MyItems. How can I make it Persistable and ensure that MyItem contents is really stored, no matter how complex that object is?

And why is [IntHashtable](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/IntHashtable.html) listed as Persistable, but Hashtable is not?

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805182/how-do-i-use-the-persistent-object-store-in-blackberry/3808672#3808672  Also: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_objects_persistently_1219782_11.jsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You listed Hashtable yourself when you wrote the part about Implicit Persistence, not sure what more you want to verify that it is Persistable. At any rate, if you want MyItems to be Persistable, just do `public class MyItems implements Persistable` as its declaration. The way it works is that if you want something to be Persistable, anything that it keeps a copy of (ie, it's member variables) needs to be Persistable as well. So if MyItems needs to store a String, a Vector of Integers, and a MyItem, you need to make sure MyItem is Persistable as well.

This will give you some limitations on what you can save. For instance, you won't be able to create a Persistable MyItems if one of its member variables is a Bitmap. Also note that using a non-Persistable object inside of a method won't prevent you from being able to make the class itself Persistable.

Comment: True, sorry - I didn't notice the Hashtable in the doc. Also I think Vector and Hashtable can't have " implements Persistable", because that would change their Java-"fingerprint". But for net.rim.device.api.util.IntHashtable it is okay, because it's a RIM class.

Comment: @Alexander Farber, Vector and Hastable are already Persistable. If the object in the Vector doesen't implements Persistable, the application will crash on setContent().