# Delete Persistent Store data when App is uninstalled/deleted

Tags: blackberry, persistent, persistent-storage

I have a BlackBerry application that starts (App load) with a Registration screen when the App is first installed. Later, the App will load with the home screen. Registration screen only appears on first load. I am achieving this by storing a `boolean` value in `PersistentStore`. If the value exists, then Registration screen will not appear.

```
PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.put("flagged",Boolean.TRUE);
PersistentStoreHelper.persistentObject.commit();
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyScreen());
```

I am aware of the fact that in order to delete the Persistent Store on deleting/uninstalling the App, I have to make the Hashtable a subclass of my own and therefore I have declared the Hashtable in a separate class:

```
public class PersistentStoreHelper extends Hashtable implements Persistable{

    public static PersistentObject persistentObject;
    public static final long KEY = 0x9df9f961bc6d6daL;
    public static Hashtable persistentHashtable;

}
```

However this has not helped and the `boolean` value of flag is not cleared from `PersistentStore`. Please advice.

---

**EDIT**: When I change the above **PersistentStoreHelper** class to

```
public static PersistentObject persistentObject =
    PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY);
```

and remove

```
PersistentStoreHelper.persistentObject = 
    PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(PersistentStoreHelper.KEY);
```

from class B where `boolean` value is being saved, I observe that the `boolean` value is removed every time the App is closed. This should not happen and the value should only be removed in case the App is deleted/uninstalled. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this works is that the BlackBerry OS looks at the objects you are storing in the `PersistentStore`.  If it recognizes that those objects can only be used by your app, then it will delete them when you uninstall the app.  However, if the classes of the stored objects are classes that are used by other apps, then your data will **not** be deleted.

You have declared your helper class like this:

```java
public class PersistentStoreHelper extends Hashtable implements Persistable{
```

but the helper class is not what is being stored.  Your helper class is just a *helper*, that stores other things for you.  In your case, it is storing this:

```java
public static Hashtable persistentHashtable;
```

but, that object is of type `java.util.Hashtable`, which is a class used by many apps.  So, it won't be deleted when you uninstall your app.  What you should do is something like this:

```java
public class PersistentStoreHelper implements Persistable {  // so inner class = Persistable

    public static PersistentObject persistentObject;
    public static final long KEY = 0x9df9f961bc6d6daL;
    /** 
      * persistentHashtable is now an instance of a class that
      * only exists in your app 
      */
    public static MyAppsHashtable persistentHashtable;

    private class MyAppsHashtable extends Hashtable implements Persistable {
        // don't need anything else ... the declaration does it all!
    }
}
```

I can't see it here, but I'm assuming that somewhere you have this code:

```java
persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY);
```

and then when you want to save the data back to the store, you're doing something like this;

```java
persistentHashtable.put("SomeKey", someNewData);
persistentObject.setContents(persistentHashtable);
persistentObject.commit();
```

just adding data to the `persistentHashtable` doesn't save it (permanently).  Hopefully, you already had that part somewhere.

---

**Note:** if you make these changes, don't expect this line of code to work, the next time you run your app:

```java
persistentHashtable = (MyAppsHashtable)persistentObject.getContents();
```

because the last version of your code did not use the `MyAppsHashtable` class, so the loaded data won't be of that type.  This is one reason that it's important to get this right the first time.  In general, I always wind up saving data in the `PersistentStore` that's contained in one top level `Hashtable` *subclass*, that implements `Persistable`.  I may later change what goes in it, but I won't ever change the signature of that top-level storage object.  Hopefully, you haven't released your app already.

---

**Update:**  In response to your comment/question below:

```java
if (PersistentStoreHelper.persistentObject.getContents() == null) {   
    PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable = new MyAppsHashtable();    
    PersistentStoreHelper.persistentObject.setContents(PersistentStoreHelper.persist‌entHashtable); 
} else { 
    PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable = 
        (MyAppsHashtable)PersistentStoreHelper.persistentObject.getContents(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nate. I am trying to work it around. Previously I was calling the following way to getContents:
`if (PersistentStoreHelper.persistentObject.getContents() == null) 
     {
      PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable = new Hashtable();
      PersistentStoreHelper.persistentObject.setContents(PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable);
     } else {
      PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable = (Hashtable)PersistentStoreHelper. persistentObject.getContents();`
       }
I am unable to edit to: `persistentHashtable = (MyAppsHashtable)persistentObject.getContents();` How to go about?

Comment: @Sarah, Please see my second update in the answer above.  Thanks.

Comment: I have been working with the Edit you provided but its not helping; I get a type mismatch: `Cannot convert from Hashtable to PersistentStoreHelper.MyAppsHashtable`. Can you please help? EDIT: The issue is now at `PersistentStoreHelper.persistentObject.setContents(PersistentStoreHelper.persist‌entHashtable);`. This line is giving an error: persist‌entHashtable cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: @Sarah, I can't see your exact code, but I can guess that your problem has to do with the fact that you're not using `PersistentStoreHelper` as a real **class**.  You're just dumping things in there.  What you should do is keep all the code needed to load and save from the persistent store **inside** this class, and handle initializing the store, from within this class. I'm pretty sure you're not doing that.  First of all, all the `public static` variables in your code should be `private`.  Then, the code at the bottom of my answer should really be inside a constructor, or `initialize()` ...

Comment: .. method of the `PeristentStoreHelper` class. When you do that, then you don't have to write `PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable`. You just write `persistentHashtable`. All that code should be inside a `PersistentStoreHelper` method (or constructor). Then, the compiler will be able to see the private `MyAppsHashtable` class. It's really important to understand this concept before going further, or your Java code will have lots of problems. I recommend looking at [something like this tutorial online.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)

Comment: @Sarah, Also, I put a sample implementation of the `PersistentStoreHelper` class, that I think would be much cleaner than what you're trying to work with, [online here](http://pastebin.com/tka4jQvF).  An example of how to use it from outside the class is shown in the class comments at the top of the file.

Comment: Thank you @Nate. While I still havent implemented the class completely, your answer is well explained and has made things clear. I will be working on it.

Comment: I know the answer is accepted but can you help me; I have implemented the above and the App loads fine on the simulator but on the device it gives me an error `Class Cast Exception`. Can you comment?

Comment: **where** do you get that exception?  which line?  did you check my **Note:** in the answer about running after changing the code to use MyAppsHashtable?

Comment: Yes I did check your **Note**. I have not called `persistentHashtable = (MyAppsHashtable)persistentObject.getContents();` anywhere in my code. I am calling my main class (start App) like this:
`PersistentStoreHelper.getInstance();
       PersistentStoreHelper.persistentObject= PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(PersistentStoreHelper.KEY); 
       if (PersistentStoreHelper.getInstance().get("flagged")!=null) 
        {
        boolean booleanVal = ((Boolean) PersistentStoreHelper.getInstance().get("flagged")).booleanValue();`

Comment: debugging is not helping since the App works on the simulator but not on the actual device.

Comment: @Sarah, well in the short chunk of code you just posted, the only place you could get a `ClassCastException` would be where you cast the result of `get("flagged")` to a `Boolean`.  If you originally called `put("flagged", value)` with a value that was not a `Boolean` object, then you'll get that exception.  Also, you **can** run in the debugger, with the app on your device, as long as it's connected via the USB cable.